# How to add variance to df.summary() pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

In Pyspark I have this dataframe, I need to work out the mean, max min, standard deviation, variance, 25th, 50th and 75th percentile.

```py
+----+-----------+------+----------+------------------+
|x|   y           |z    |a           | b              |
+----+-----------+------+----------+------------------+
|   3|         10|     9| 206000018| 4.406719247264253|
|   3|          8|     3| 206000013|4.5217885770490405|
|   2|          5|     7| 206000014| 4.219507705176107|
|   3|          7|     7| 206000014| 4.442651256490317|
|   3|          8|     5| 206000013| 4.477336814478207|
|   3|          3|     3| 206000013| 4.406719247264253|
|   3|          3|     2| 206000013| 4.543294782270004|
|   4|         11|     0| 206000015| 4.532599493153256|
|   2|          6|     7| 206000014| 4.219507705176107|
|   3|         12|     0| 206000014| 4.584967478670572|
|   2|         10|     7| 206000014| 4.189654742026425|
|   3|         12|     0| 206000013|4.3694478524670215|
|   4|          8|     2| 206000014| 4.477336814478207|
|   3|         12|     0| 206000013| 4.330733340286331|
|   2|          7|     7| 206000018|4.1588830833596715|
|   2|         10|     6| 206000015| 4.143134726391533|
|   2|          5|     7| 206000014|3.8918202981106265|
|   3|         13|     5| 206000014| 4.553876891600541|
|   3|         12|     0| 206000018| 4.564348191467836|
|   2|         12|     8| 206000014|3.7376696182833684|
+----+-----------+------+----------+------------------+
```

I used df.summary() but its missing variance how would I solve this issue

```py
+-------+------------------+----------------+------------------+------------+------------+--------------------+------------------+
|summary|              x|     y|            z|a                  |b         |            num|           rent|
+-------+------------------+----------------+------------------+------------+------------+--------------------+------------------+
|  count|               677|             677|               677|           0|           0|                 677|               677|
|   mean| 2.124076809453471| 9.3205317577548|1.9601181683899558|        null|        null|3.1210000908419496E8| 6.334028871646328|
| stddev|0.9114472106272636|4.68243675002651|1.9284245610836643|        null|        null|   4.810337873333296|  0.63003755584204|
|    min|               0.0|             1.0|               0.0|        null|        null|        3.12100001E8|1.0986122886681098|
|    25%|               2.0|             5.0|               0.0|        null|        null|        3.12100007E8| 6.142037405587356|
|    50%|               2.0|            11.0|               2.0|        null|        null|        3.12100009E8| 6.396929655216146|
|    75%|               3.0|            14.0|               4.0|        null|        null|        3.12100011E8| 6.635946555686647|
|    max|               5.0|            18.0|               6.0|        null|        null|        3.12100018E8| 8.024862150286411|
+-------+------------------+----------------+------------------+------------+------------+--------------------+------------------+
```

Please ignore the extra 2 columns added

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [pyspark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.summary.html), variance is not available for .summary(). However, since `variance = (standard deviation)^2` you can just add this calculation to your result.